# Should I remove the influential points in this case?

Tags: r, regression, cooks-distance

I build a linear model from a small dataset with

```
Income <- c(23663, 20659, 32277, 21595, 27227, 
       25023, 26504, 28741, 21735, 23366, 
       20871, 28370, 21105, 22706, 19527, 
       28321)
Education   <- c(0.19, 0.16, 0.40, 0.24, 0.31, 0.24, 0.28, 
         0.31, 0.18, 0.23, 0.17, 0.31, 0.15, 0.25, 
         0.19, 0.28) # Education is a fraction of obtaining the bachelor's degree
dat = data.frame(Income, Education)
row.names(dat) <- c("Androscoggin", "Aroostook", "Cumberland", "Franklin", "Hancock","Kennebec", "Knox", "Lincoln", "Oxford", "Penobscot", "Piscataquis", "Sagadahoc", "Somerset", "Waldo", "Washington", "York")
```

The linear model

```
m = lm(Income ~ Education, dat)
```

Plot the cook-distance

```
cutoff = (nrow(dat) -2-1-1)/4)
plot(m, which =4,cook.levels = cutoff )
```

[image: cook.distance.plot]

I saw the Cook's distance value of Franklin, Washington, Somerset stick out like a sore thumb from the other values.
So I decided to remove them from the dat data and make a new model

```
influential_points = c("Washington",  "Franklin" ,  "Somerset")
m.influen = lm(Income~ Education, data =dat[!row.names(dat) %in% influential_points,])

m.influen= lm(formula = Income ~ Education, data = dat[!row.names(dat) %in% 
            influential_points, ])
```

I compare the new (m.influen) and old(m) model

m Model:

```
summary(m)

Call:
lm(formula = Income ~ Education, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2730.4  -490.9   249.5   757.9  2008.8 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    12404       1350   9.186 2.64e-07 ***
Education      49670       5355   9.275 2.35e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1432 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.86, Adjusted R-squared:   0.85 
F-statistic: 86.03 on 1 and 14 DF,  p-value: 2.353e-07
```

m.influen Model:

```
summary(m.influen)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2412.71  -354.62   -74.61   390.93  1742.39 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    12953       1193   10.85 3.24e-07 ***
Education      48664       4533   10.74 3.62e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1095 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9129,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.905 
F-statistic: 115.3 on 1 and 11 DF,  p-value: 3.62e-07
```

There is no significant difference between the estimation of parameters in 2 models, but the R-squared value was improved in m.infulen model compares with m(old) model.

My question is : Should I remove them from the model? If I remove them, the model2(m.influen) can perform for several validation sets  better than the model1(m)

Comment: Instead of removing data points you should add other predictors to your model. Income clearly does not only depend on education. Any recruiter and most people who have searched for a job can tell you this.

Comment: @Roland Many Thanks. You are awesome. A very precious experience.

Comment: It is usually more informative to use the plot of residuals versus influence with contours of Cook's distance. But as @Roland says removing them is the absolute last resort.

Comment: @mdewey, Thanks for you reply,  I just took a simple bivariate model for an example. In practice, when I do a multi-regression analysis with several explanatory variables, I think removing the influential points is a good idea to create a better model even if it does not change the estimated parameters too much. What do you think about it? Please share  your opinion.

Comment: If it does not change the parameters why would you want to remove them? If it does change them what grounds are there for preferring one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't remove data points from your model just because  they don't fit the rest of the data! It is likely that there are other factors that will influence income other than education - a purely linear relationship between income and education is unlikely. As Roland mentioned other predictors should be added to your model.